# How does Ubuntu formats any flash drive with file systems in terms of Code?

Tags: usb, files, filesystem, development, c

I was thinking how can we design a file system of our own for study and experimental purpose.

But for doing that I am not able to find proper documentation and resources.

I also want to know even if somehow I am able to develop a file system but how can I format that to my given drive. What kind of code is to be written for that?

If anyone knows how this all works and what are the resources which can be referred then please help.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  If you look in `/sbin` & the 'mk*' program binaries you'll find many like `mkdosfs`, `mke2fs`, `mkexfatfs`, `mkfs.ext2` etc.  `mkfs.ext4` will make a ext4 file-system (ie. format), `mkfs.fat` will make a fat fs, Reference doco is available with `man mkfs.ntfs` or whatever file-system you're interested in, as this is open-source you can grab the source code, with loads of file-systems there for you to look at.

Answer (score 5):

If you look in `/sbin' & the 'mk*' program binaries that will make file-systems (ie. format)

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   ls /sbin/mk*
/sbin/mkdosfs    /sbin/mkfs         /sbin/mkfs.exfat  /sbin/mkfs.ext4  /sbin/mkfs.minix  /sbin/mkfs.reiser4   /sbin/mkfs.xfs          /sbin/mkreiser4
/sbin/mke2fs     /sbin/mkfs.bfs     /sbin/mkfs.ext2   /sbin/mkfs.fat   /sbin/mkfs.msdos  /sbin/mkfs.reiserfs  /sbin/mkhomedir_helper  /sbin/mkreiserfs
/sbin/mkexfatfs  /sbin/mkfs.cramfs  /sbin/mkfs.ext3   /sbin/mkfs.jfs   /sbin/mkfs.ntfs   /sbin/mkfs.vfat      /sbin/mkntfs            /sbin/mkswap
```

`mkfs.fat` will make a FAT fs, `mkfs.ntfs` will create a NTFS file-system etc.

Reference manual pages are available with `man mkfs.ntfs` or whatever file-system you're interested in.

As this is open-source you can grab the source code, having loads of file-systems there for you to look at.  If I wanted to grab source code for 'ext4' (or the `mkfs.ext4` program), i can see what package i need with

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   dpkg -S /sbin/mkfs.ext4 
e2fsprogs: /sbin/mkfs.ext4
```

the grab the source with `sudo apt source e2fsprogs`

Comment: I didn't say it, but most programs will call these program binaries to do the actual make-file-system or 'format'. These are not all the file systems Ubuntu knows about, just what were on my Ubuntu 18.10 system from which I answered.